# Having all website paths load the same static website in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my express server, I want to have all paths load the same static website, which I tried doing with the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('*', express.static('build'));
app.listen(3000);
```

Unfortunately I am presented with the following console errors when I navigate to any path on localhost:

```
:3000/main.js/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

When attempting to view the JS file with the error, it seems to be serving index.html in its place.

I know this is due to the wildcard, but I can't think of a way to cleanly exclude all file names and paths from the static server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something a little more like this..`app.use(express.static('public')`

if your tree looks like

```html
ProjectName
| server.js
| public
   | index.html
```

you don't need the * as a parameter since setting the express.static sets the folder open to public view. This is how you separate your server code and client code. Be careful not to expose your entire project directory as people will then have access to your server code. This is why you're client files should be kept in a public folder or a www folder (common practices)

--EDIT

```js
//this will server css, and js files so they can be linked into the html
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//this will force all url's except the public files to be given the index.html file.
app.use('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.
Unfortunately a simple static server wouldn't serve the static files to any subdirectory within the website. Only to the root.

Comment: that shouldn't be the case look at the example [at expresses docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) specifically `app.use('/router', express.static('public'));` their output shows you can go into other folder like images/kittens.jpg you should be able to go into sub directories without any issues

Comment: What I'm currently trying to achieve is having "/index.html" load, even if the path being navigated to is "/this/can/be/anything/".
Unfortunately a plain static server isn't don't the trick for me.

Comment: then what about using this `app.use('*', function(req,res) { res.sendFile(__dirname + 'public/index.html'))};` that way every route will get served the index.html page.

Comment: @AndreiM. if you put that _after_ `app.use(express.static(...))`, it should work. You can even drop the `'*'` argument.

Comment: I like to keep the * symbol so I can search for it later and easier to read then just having to remember that If there isn't * it means all routes

Comment: It appears my JS file isn't loading correctly with the suggested configuration.
When looking in my sources, it appears main.js is loading the file contents of index.html.

Comment: i bet it's because you are using the url like `localhost:3000/public/js/script.js` the public will not be part of the url as it mounts it's contents. So the url you are looking for would instead be `localhost:3000/js/scripts.js' if there is a js folder and a scripts.js file inside the public folder. you are getting the html back because you aren't on the right url

Comment: This is likely due to the wildcard catching all paths and sending the index.html file.
When the browser is fetching scripts.js, index.html is being served.

Comment: express is a smart cookie. if you add the express.static it will make sure those paths are not over-written by the * route unless they are explicitly being over written later with an identical path to the served path.